# How to create a shared library using object library in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, build, linker

I have two shared libraries each one having its own CMakeLists.txt. The directory structure is like this.

```
main_dir
|--- subdir
|    |--- src1.cpp
|    |--- src2.cpp
|    |--- src3.cpp
|    |--- CMakeLists.txt
|--- src11.cpp
|--- CMakeLists.txt
```

Currently, I am able to build both main library and sub library (say main.so and sub.so).

The CMakeLists.txt for both looks as below.

main_dir/CMakeLists.txt

```
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build the shared library" ON)

if(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
  add_library(mainlib SHARED)
endif()

target_sources(mainlib PRIVATE
  src11.cpp
)

add_subdirectory(subdir)
```

subdir/CMakeLists.txt

```
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build the shared library" ON)

if(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
  add_library(sublib SHARED)
endif()

target_sources(sublib PRIVATE
  src1.cpp
  src2.cpp
  src3.cpp)
```

Now I want the object file or symbols of sub library to be included in the main library as well, so that users can still use the main library alone even if they don't link their application to the sub library.

I'm new to CMake and I was trying to create an object library out of all source files in the sub_dir and link this to my mainlib.

```
add_library(subarchive OBJECT src1.cpp src2.cpp src3.cpp)
target_sources(mainlib INTERFACE $<TARGET_OBJECTS:subarchive>)
```

But It gives me error.

```
(add_library) No SOURCES given to target: mainlib
```

How can I create an object library in sub_dir and add it to both sublib and mainlib. Is there any better way to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it working by setting PARENT_SCOPE for the object library in the suddirectory. The modifications to the original code look like this.

main_dir/CMakeLists.txt

```
set(SUBARCHIVE_OBJECTS)

add_subdirectory(subdir)
target_link_libraries(mainlib private ${SUBARCHIVE_OBJECTS}
```

subdir/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(subarchive OBJECT src1.cpp src2.cpp src3.cpp)
list(APPEND SUBARCHIVE_OBJECTS ${TARGET_OBJECTS:subarchive>)
set(SUBARCHIVE_OBJECTS ${SUBARCHIVE_OBJECTS} PARENT_SCOPE)
```

Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Any reference of your suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

To use an `OBJECT` library, link with it. That doesn't do any actual linking -- there is no "thing" that is the object library, it's just a collection of object files that CMake knows about -- but puts the object files in the target:

```
target_link_libraries(mainlib PRIVATE sublib)
```

Here is a complete example (it creates source files `one.cpp` and `two.cpp` so that it is entirely self-contained):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(example)
if(NOT EXISTS one.cpp)
  file(WRITE one.cpp "int x;")
endif()
if(NOT EXISTS two.cpp)
  file(WRITE two.cpp "int y;")
endif()
add_library(sublib OBJECT one.cpp)
add_library(mainlib SHARED two.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mainlib PRIVATE sublib)
```

Comment: I understand that adding target_link_libraries(mainlib PRIVATE sublib) should include the symbols of sublib to the mainlib.  But I want my sublib also to exist as a shared library for now.  so can I still use target_sources(sublib PRIVATE
  src1.cpp
  src2.cpp
  src3.cpp) to create shared lib and also make an OBJECT so that it can be included in the mainlib.  As Just doing this add_library(sublib OBJECT one.cpp) will make my sublib as an OBJECT and not the shared lib.  Hope I made it clear.

Comment: you can use `add_library(sublib_o OBJECT ..)` and `add_library(sublib SHARED ..)` to make two targets, or, now I think about it some more, `target_link_library(mainlib PUBLIC sublib)` might do the trick, too. It depends a little on whether you need consumers to be able to call the sublib-api or just need the mailib to use it.

Comment: I have tried with target_link_library(mainlib PUBLIC sublib), the mainlib is built, but when I compile a small test which ls linked to mainlib,  it gives me the error "ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: function
>>> referenced by test.cpp
>>>               /tmp/test-93ddb5.o:(main)"

the symbol function is actually from the sublib.  If I link the test.cpp with -lsublib then I am able to run the exe fine. But I want the consumers to be able to use with just mainlib as well.  What am I missing.   nm -D sublib  shows the symbol, however nm -D mainlib doesnt show the symbol.